# The smallest size of generators of a finite module over a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a *finite* commutative ring (non-zero and with a unit element). Now consider the module $M := R^n$, i.e. $n$-tuples of element of $R$. It is clear that $M$ is free (i.e. has a basis), and it is known that $R$ is an invariant basis number ring (as $R$ is a commutative ring). Thus the size of any basis of $M$ is the same, which is called the *rank* of $M$ (the rank is $n$ is this case).

Now let $M'$ be a submodule of $M$. $M'$ need not be free. For example, consider $R = \mathbb{Z}_4$, $n=1$, and $M' = \{0, 2\}$. Thus the traditional notion of *rank* cannot be defined for $M'$. However, note that this quantity is perfectly well defined for $M'$: let $G \subseteq M'$ be a generating set of $M'$ (which clearly exists as $R$ is finite and hence so is $M'$), and suppose $\mathcal{G}$ is the collection of all such generating sets, then define $\text{dim}(M') := \min_{G \in \mathcal{G}} |G|$. When $M'$ is free, this quantity is exactly equal to the rank of $M'$.

I want to know if this quantity has a ''more standard'' name or not, with a **reference if it exists somewhere**. I am fairly new to Algebra and studying it from Lang's "Algebra" and Brown's "Matrices over commutative rings" textbooks, because of a specific problem that I encountered while writing a paper, and I do not see this quantity defined therein, or anywhere I looked so far on the internet.

Here is more context to why the above defined quantity is interesting to me. Suppose I define a matrix $A \in R^{n \times p}$. I want to talk about the ''dimension'' of the submodule (call it $M'$) of $R^n$ generated by the columns of $A$. I cannot simply call it the rank, as $M'$ may not be free. But the quantity $\text{dim}(M')$ makes perfect sense. So let us define $\text{colrank}(A) := \text{dim}(M')$. Then one can easily show that $\text{colrank}(A) = \text{colrank}(PAQ)$, where $P \in R^{n \times n}$ and $Q \in R^{p \times p}$ are both invertible matrices over $R$. This property is important for the problem I'm studying.

Comment: Perhaps this is related to [Nakayama's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma#Local_rings)?

Comment: This quantity is generally referred to as the minimal number of generators of $M'$. However, if the ring $R$ is not local, there is some pathology around behavior of generating sets that one has to be careful of. This number is most commonly studied in  the local case where you can find it denoted $\mu_R(M)$ (or sometimes $\nu_R(M)$). In this case it agrees with the size of a minimal (under inclusion) generating set.